# Using ".." in SQL (INSERT INTO X..Y (A) VALUES ('1')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just unsure what use of ".." means. I cannot google it due to characters itself. I think it can be written also that way?: INSERT INTO X.dbo.Y. Or what is it?
Thank you

Comment: sql server? access? mysql? oracle?

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before. Is that standard SQL? Are you sure that it was't just pseudo code from an example which indicates a range of columns? What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it tells you to use the default schema in sql servers

these 2 are the same

```
select * from master..sysobjects

select * from master.dbo.sysobjects
```

Comment: Thank you..I do not know much about schemas. What it looks like if you wanted to use different one?

Comment: As I've just posted - if you want it to use a different schema then dbo, just make that the default schema for the user who's issuing the command

Comment: you would change dbo to the other schema name. So if the schema name is HR it would be select * from master.HR.sysobjects

Answer (score 1):

It takes the default schema for the current logged in user, not necessarily dbo, as others have posted.

So if there are two tables in the target database, e.g. dbo.Users and Client.Users, and you issue a "select * from DB..Users", then the results will vary based on whether the person who issues the query has dbo or Client as their default schema.

And for more info, look under the Multipart names section of [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly translated your insert statement translates to

- Insert - I am sure you got that bit
- INTO   - Part of the insert statement
- X     - The Database you want to insert into
- dbo   - The Schema owner
- Y     - The Table